# Java math function like this math equation?

Tags: java, math, equation

Is there any kind of Java math function like what this math equation does?

```
A_value = A_min + (B_value-B_min)/B_max*A_max
```

So it would be like this:

```
0 + (5-0)/10*5
```

That would be equal to 2.5.
Is there any kind of math function like this? When B increases its value by a set minimum and maximum, A's value increases by a set minimum and maximum.

Comment: Most likely there is no built-in method that does this exactly. However, you can easily implement your own.

Comment: furher you should know whats the name of that function! othetwise you could not find it, even when one exist!

Comment: The A and the B are two different numbers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is one!

```
public static double aValue(double aMin, double aMax, double bValue, double bMin, double bMax) {
  return aMin + (bValue - bMin)/(aMax * bMax);
}
```

I'm not sure what you're talking about, actually, but I'm pretty sure Java doesn't have it. Here's the [Java Math functions class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)